# A* Neo4j return all paths and conditions on edges

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, shortest-path, neo4j-apoc

I'm currently using the apoc
 library to get the shortest path with a cost (length)

```
apoc.algo.aStar(
    startNode, endNode, 'KNOWS|<WORKS_WITH|IS_MANAGER_OF>', 
    'distance','lat','lon'
) YIELD path, weight
```

There are two things I need:

1. How would I go about making it return all possible paths and not just the one?
2. How would I make it only search egdes where PropertyA: true, PropertyB: false, PropertyC contains "abc", etc..?

The answer doesn't have to be using apoc but can be with CYPHER or C# please.
Thanks

Comment: While that would be an epic and dramatic name, it's actually the APOC library (standing both for Awesome Procedures On Cypher, and referencing the character of Apoc from The Matrix).

Comment: Haha. Autocorrect on my phone. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answering to your first question you can use `allShortestPaths` function. For your second question you can set a `WHERE CONDITION` or your relationship.

This is my try on my sample database:

```
MATCH path=allShortestPaths((:User)-[:MEMBER_OF_GROUP*1..3]-(:Group)) WHERE ALL(x in relationships(path) WHERE x.last_seen > 1534326850) RETURN path
```

You need add your path in `allShortestPaths` and for search on edges check path relations in `WHERE CONDITION`

Comment: Doesn't that just return all paths that are the same length?

Comment: If you need all paths just remove allShortestPaths func

Comment: Works very slowly when removing allShortestPaths but I know of a workaround.

Comment: @Liam Notice that *1..3 will try to check all possible paths between two node so it will cause big delay in response. be caution in selecting numbers